# Changing $y=mx+b$ equation into $ax+by=c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on this question and I'm not totally sure how to transform an equation of the form $y=mx+b$ into an equation of the form $ax+by=c$. This is how far I have gotten

$$y=-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{29}{3}$$

How do I transform this into an $ax+by=c$ equation?

Answer (score 3):

Typically when changing from the the $y = mx+b$ form (slope-intercept form)  to the $ax+by=c$ form (standard form) you want $a$ and $b$ to be integers. First we can multiply both sides by three (because this is the denominator of the slope $m$), then just move the term with $x$ to the other side of the equation by adding $x$ to both sides:
$$\begin{align}
  y&=-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{29}{3}\\
  3(y)&=3\left(-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{29}{3}\right)\\
  3y&=-x+29\\\\
  x + 3y &= 29
\end{align}$$

More generally, if you wanted $a$,$b$, and $c$ to be integers in the standard form, you would first have to take the denominators of $m$ and $b$ from the slope-intercept form and multiply through by their *least common multiple* (in our case here, that least common multiple happens to just be $3$).

Comment: If you're going to invent a requirement of integer coefficients, you should at least discuss how this isn't possible if $m$ and/or $b$ is irrational ...

Answer (score 1):

You transform it into
$$
\frac{1}{3} x + y = \frac{29}{3}
$$
by adding $(1/3) x$ to both sides of the equation. So you got $a = 1/3$ and $b = 1$ and $c = 29/3$.

In fact for $\lambda \ne 0$ the set of solutions $(x,y)$ does not change, if we multiply both sides by $\lambda$:
$$
\frac{\lambda}{3}x + \lambda y = \frac{29\lambda}{3}
$$
Among all those equations one can decide for a nice looking one, in this case $\lambda = 3$ looks a bit less complex (no division):
$$
x + 3y = 29
$$

Comment: dont you have to divide it by 3?

Comment: @Student909 you probably meant multiply?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer !!

Comment: @windircurse yes I meant multiply, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you  write it in the format $ax +by =c$ you want the coefficients to be integers for simplicity. But dividing the coefficients won't affect the properties of the line in anyway. The following equations represent the same line.

$y= \frac{-1}{3} x +\frac{29}{3}$

$ \frac{1}{3} x+y=\frac{29}{3}$

$x+ 3y=29$